# Can't find file to patch at input line 11, File to patch:?

Tags: 6, uri, testing

I got an error message on module installation simpletest

> SimpleTest could not be installed. Must apply core patch, please see INSTALL.txt. (Currently using SimpleTest code addition Not-found)

Then by the instruction provided by INSTALL.txt I run the command

> ioss@ioss-System-Product-Name:~$ patch -p0 < /var/www/Drupal/beeone/sites/all/modules/simpletest/D6-core-simpletest.patch

Then I got error below

```
can't find file to patch at input line 11
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|? sites/all/modules
|? sites/default/files
|? sites/default/settings.php
|Index: install.php
|===================================================================
|RCS file: /cvs/drupal/drupal/install.php,v
|retrieving revision 1.113.2.12
|diff -u -p -r1.113.2.12 install.php
|--- install.php    9 May 2010 14:13:31 -0000   1.113.2.12
|+++ install.php    7 Oct 2010 21:55:51 -0000
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch is trying to alter the install.php file that comes with Drupal, but it doesn't find it. That file is normally removed, once Drupal has been installed.

What the command line is prompting for is the name of the file to patch, in the case has been renamed, or moved in a different directory.

Keep in mind that the SimpleTest module should not be installed in a production server, but in a development site.